Using implicit function theorem to find functions
I am working on a practice problem for a real analysis homework and could use some hints/help on its parts based on my current attempts and progress. Thank you in advance.
The problem states:
Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $$f(x,y,c)=\begin{pmatrix} x+cy^2-1, \\ y-cx-2 \end{pmatrix}$$ and the system of equations $f(x,y,c)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, do the following:
a) Prove that there exist $C^\infty$ functions $x(c)$ and $y(c)$ defined for $c\in(-a,a)$ for some $a>0$ such that $x(0)=1$ and $y(0)=2$ and $f(x(c),y(c),c)= \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$
b) Find $x'(0)$ and $y'(0).$
For part (a), here is my approach: I confirmed that taking $x=1,y=2,c=0$ I get $f(1,2,0)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$ Then, I calculated the Jacobian for this and I got $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Based on this, since this Jacobian is clearly invertible (it's the identity), then the implicit function theorem guarantees the existence of $x(c)$ and $y(c)$ as wanted. I am not sure if my proof is correct and makes sense. I am also not sure how to show that these $x(c)$ and $y(c)$ are $C^\infty$ functions or if that's just a consequence of the implicit function theorem. Any advice on approaching part b would also be appreciated. Thank you

The Implicit Function Theorem is usually stated assuming $f\in C^k$. But if $f$ is $C^\infty$, then it’s in $C^k$ for every $k$, and so the implicitly defined functions will be $C^k$ for every $k$, hence $C^\infty$.

So the way I did the proof suffices? To just find the Jacobian and then state the implicit function theorem implies there exist x and y in $C^\infty$?

You need to specify what you mean by “the Jacobian for this.” And I,do not know how the theorem was stated/proved in your course.
